# Need to restrict text with [ at beginning

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

```
@Pattern("^\\[")
```

Does not work.

Sample inputs:

`Welcome[Hello` - Pass

`Welcome[` - Pass

`[Welcome` - Fail

- Pass

```
@Pattern("^(?!\\[).*")
```

was suggested from stackoverflow.
But when inserting new line char (`\n`) it doesn't seems working

```
public final static String FREE_TEXT_FIELD_VALIDATION_PATTERN = "^(?!\\[).*";

@Pattern(regexp = FREE_TEXT_FIELD_VALIDATION_PATTERN, message = FREE_TEXT_FIELD_VALIDATION_ERROR) 
public String ruleDescription;
```

Comment: Try `\A(?!\\[).*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^\[.*$
```

---

```
^ = start of string
\[ = escaped '[' character
.* = zero or more of any character except newline
```

Welcome[Hello - Fail

Welcome[ - Fail

[Welcome - Pass

You can test here https://regexr.com/

### **Edit**

If you want to match anything who NOT START with [ but allow line break

```
^(?!(\[))\w+((.|\n)*)$
```

---

```
Welcome[Hello - Pass

Welcome[ - Pass

[Welcome - Pass

[Welcome

test.    - PASS
```

### Edit 2

```
^(?!(\[))\w+((.|\n)*)$|^$
```

We add |^$ for allow empty string

| is used to denote alternates this|that.

Comment: I need to restrict string with [ at beginning but it may contain multiple lines of text, even a empty string

Comment: @AnandKumar 
I didn't quite understand, now it's what you want?

Comment: Empty string evaluates to false

Comment: We add |^$ for allow empty string

Comment: @AnandKumar Put in solved if it's work like you want ;)